# CXF REST Bean Validation gives a 404 Not Found instead of 400 Bad Request

Tags: http-status-code-404, bean-validation, numberformatexception, http-status-code-400, cxfrs

I have a CXF RS Rest Resource which looks like this :

```
public class SomeRestResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("path")
    public Response getResource(

        @DecimalMin(value = "0.01", message="Weight should be minimum {value}.")
        @Digits( integer = 5, fraction = 2, message = "Weight should be maximum of {integer} integer and {fraction} fractional digits." )
        @QueryParam("weight") double weight)

        // do some operations with weight here...
        }      
     }
```

I am expecting the REST client to enter the weight as a **double** with minimum value of **0.01** and a maximum value of 5 digits and 2 fractions in the format **xxxxx.yy**.

When I test this REST resource using the value of weight as **0**, it gives me a **400 BAD REQUEST** with the message **Weight should be maximum of 0.01** which is **correct**!

But, when I enter the value of weight as **AB**, it gives me a **404 NOT FOUND** at the client side, and fails with the following Java exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AB"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Double.java:504)
at org.apache.cxf.common.util.PrimitiveUtils.read(PrimitiveUtils.java:75)
at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.utils.InjectionUtils.handleParameter(InjectionUtils.java:361)
```

Shouldn't it recognize the input type as **not a double** and validate against the **datatype** as well? What should I do so that it returns a 400 for input strings like AB as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an ugly workaround for this which is to keep the datatypes for all the query parameters in the REST resource to `String` and then apply validation on those Strings using **regular expressions**. For instance, for the above mentioned scenario for a `double` with minimum value of 0.01 and a maximum value of 5 digits and 2 fractions in the format **xxxxx.yy**, it can be done in the following way :

```
public class SomeRestResource {

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("path")
public Response getResource(

    @NotNull @Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9]{0,5}[.]{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$")
    @QueryParam("weight") String weight)

    // do some operations with weight here...
    }      
 }
```

Now, if a REST client enters the value of **AB** for weight, it will give a 400 BAD REQUEST.